# Counting Nucleotide in string python

Tags: python, list, counting

Good afternoon. I am currently taking a bioinformatics using Python and I've hit a road block.

I'm trying to right code to count the number of nucleotide in a string. This is the code I've used so far:

```
DNA = "ACgttGTcgtTTgaCCGacACCGGTTAACCGGTACGGTAACAAGGTTTAGGTA" 

DNA_nucs = {'A':0, 'C':0, 'G':0, 'T':0}

for nucs in DNA:
    DNA_nucs[nucs]+=1
    print(DNA_nucs)
```

I also have to count the lower case letters. trying to figure out how to use the .upper attribute here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't count manually the characters, use `collections.Counter` (this is good to learn at the beginning, the *Pythonic* way of doing things):

```py
from collections import Counter

DNA = "ACgttGTcgtTTgaCCGacACCGGTTAACCGGTACGGTAACAAGGTTTAGGTA"

c = Counter(DNA.upper())
print(c)
```

Prints:

```
Counter({'G': 15, 'T': 14, 'A': 13, 'C': 11})
```

---

For comparison, using normal for-loop:

```py
DNA_nucs = {"A": 0, "C": 0, "G": 0, "T": 0}

for nucs in DNA.upper():
    DNA_nucs[nucs] += 1

print(DNA_nucs)
```

Prints:

```
{'A': 13, 'C': 11, 'G': 15, 'T': 14}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use setdefault function in your code

```
DNA = "ACgttGTcgtTTgaCCGacACCGGTTAACCGGTACGGTAACAAGGTTTAGGTA" 
result = {}
DNA_nucs = 'ACGT'
for nucs in DNA:
    if nucs in DNA_nucs:
        result.setdefault(nucs,0)
        result[nucs] += 1
result
```